# Image styles are not created, when imported from nginx

Tags: 10

I'm runnig Drupal on nginx. The nginx configuration file I am using contains the following lines.

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.duxise.com duxise.com www.duxise.cn duxise.cn www.duxingshe.cn duxingshe.cn;
    index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;
    root  /home/wwwroot/www.duxise.com;

    #include rewrite/drupal.conf;
    #error_page   404   /404.html;

    # Deny access to PHP files in specific directory
    #location ~ /(wp-content|uploads|wp-includes|images)/.*\.php$ { deny all; }

    include enable-php-pathinfo.conf;

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ /\.
    {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    access_log  /home/wwwlogs/www.duxise.com.log;
}

server
{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.duxise.com duxise.com www.duxise.cn duxise.cn www.duxingshe.cn duxingshe.cn;
    index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;
    root  /home/wwwroot/www.duxise.com;

if ( $host != 'www.duxise.com' ) {
rewrite "^/(.*)$" https://www.duxise.com/$1 permanent;
}


    ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/www.duxise.com/duxise.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/www.duxise.com/duxise.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-CCM-8-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-CCM-SHA256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5";
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    # openssl dhparam -out /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
    ssl_dhparam /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/dhparam.pem;

#   include rewrite/drupal.conf;
    #error_page   404   /404.html;

    # Deny access to PHP files in specific directory
    #location ~ /(wp-content|uploads|wp-includes|images)/.*\.php$ { deny all; }

    include enable-php-pathinfo.conf;

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
    }

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
}

location @rewrite {
    # For D7 and above:
    # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
}


#location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/(css|js)/optimized { add_header Cache-Control 'public, max-age=31536000, immutable'; }

# Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

# Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
# with a language prefix.
location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
# with a language prefix.
location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Enforce clean URLs
# Removes index.php from urls like www.example.com/index.php/my-page --> www.example.com/my-page
# Could be done with 301 (was 307) for permanent or other redirect codes.
f ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(.*)") {
    return 301 $1$2;
}



    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ /\.
    {
        deny all;
    }

    access_log  /home/wwwlogs/www.duxise.com.log;
}
```

When an image is uploaded, its image style is not generated. When I check the style folder, it does not exist, nor is it created, although the folder permissions are the following.

- sites 775
- sites/default 775
- sites/default/files 777

Comment: 777 for files is insecure, if you are using nginx as your web service you need to set owner of files folder to www-data (in ubuntu) or nginx (in centos) so `sudo chown -R www-data:$USER files/` can help in ubuntu

Comment: You need to give the /files the correct ‘owner/group’ you can see it using ‘ls -la’